# Problem with using dynamic allocation in c++

Tags: c++, dynamic

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int d(int num) {
   int dn = num;
   while (num != 0) {
      dn += num % 10;
      num = num / 10;
   }
   return dn;
}

int main() {
   int* arr = new int[10000];
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      arr[i] = i + 1;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      arr[d(i)] = 0;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      if (arr[i] > 0) {
         cout << arr[i]-1<<endl;
      }
   }
   delete[] arr;
   return 0;
}
```

I'm tying to code Self Number of D.R. Kaprekar but it doesent show any result in console with dynamic allocation but it does in using of static array.

Comment: `d(i)` can be larger than 10000. Maybe `dn` should be initialised to 0 and not `num`

Comment: @user253751 d(9999) = 10035

Comment: What problems did you find with your debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble in function

```
int d(int num) {
  int dn = num;
  while (num != 0) {
    dn += num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
  }
  return dn;
}
```

Due to, dn = num at start, return walue isn't less than num.
Don't you want to set dn to zero at start?

Answer (score 0):

The function `d` returns values with

```
d(0) == 0
```

and

```
d(i) > i, for i != 0
```

This line

```
arr[d(i)] = 0;
```

causes undefined behavior because the index goes out of bounds. In this code example you can see, how `arr[4]` is accessed though the size of this array is `3`.

```
#include<iostream>

int d(int num) {
   int dn = num;
   while (num != 0) {
      dn += num % 10;
      num = num / 10;
   }
   return dn;
}

int main() {
    constexpr unsigned int s = 3;
    int arr[s];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        arr[d(i)] = 0;
        std::cout << "d(" << i << "): " << d(i) << '\n';
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > 0) {
            std::cout << arr[i] - 1 << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
d(0): 0
d(1): 2
d(2): 4
1
```

Undefined bevahior can express itself as a crash, seemingly correct code or anything else.